# bulid a sorter and filter for a complex table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

currently I am building a complex table with huge amount of data which is a bit similar to the sample one, I would like to add sorter and filter function using jquery with a pop-up style like the image[image: sample img]
could anyone provide a solution for this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." class="myInput">
        </div>
        Firstname
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for lastnames.." class="myInput"> </div>
        Lastname
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for email.." class="myInput">
        </div>
        Email
      </th>
      <th>
        <select>
          <option></option>
          <option>x</option>
          <option>N/A</option>
        </select>
        decide
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i have added the juqery work i have done so far, seems it cannot function foe each cols. For the select part, I have no idea how to implement like the text part

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Show us what you have tried so far, we'll gladly help you.

Comment: Obviously you have to put some effort in it, and can't expect from StackOverflow that they will do the work for you. We will help you if you get stuck trying. Have a look here [jQuery Filters](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp) and here [jQuery sort Table](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp)

Comment: dear all, i have forgotten to add my jquery scripts in it, sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) , this could save you a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

made this cook for you decorate it if you liked it

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/xqp5eza2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  height:0px;
  min-width: 160px;

  padding: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition:0.3s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <span>Firstname</span>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <p> <input type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." class="myInput"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
            <div class="dropdown">
  <span>Email</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p> <input type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." class="myInput"></p>
  </div>
</div>
      </th>
      <th>
            <div class="dropdown">
  <span>Email</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p> <input type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." class="myInput"></p>
  </div>
</div>
      </th>
      <th>
                  <div class="dropdown">
  <span>Email</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>  <select>
          <option></option>
          <option>x</option>
          <option>N/A</option>
        </select></p>
  </div>
</div>
        decide
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```